# Updating from 2.5.28 to 3.5.1 FAILED HELP

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, update

I am new to this site aaand to Joomla.

The thing is I had to update to the site to 3.5.1, did all the steps from the joomla tutorial and I am getting this /see the image/ [image]

When I removed the yvbbcode folder, I got this:

[image]

When I try to access the admin panel it shows me this:

Notice: Undefined property: LoginController::$input in /www/jobs-pl.org/www/root/administrator/components/com_login/controller.php on line 36

Fatal error: Call to a member function set() on a non-object in /www/jobs-pl.org/www/root/administrator/components/com_login/controller.php on line 36

Please help! :(

Answer (score 1):

`com_login` is no longer part of core and `yvbbcode` are not part of the Joomla core at all, it's a 3rd party plugin so you'll need to find a Joomla 3.x compatible version else uninstall it.

This issue was discussed here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/11174

I would suggest trying to migrate to 3.6 rather than 3.5.1

Comment: Thank you for the answer,  but the problem is still here. Removed both com_login and yvbbcode, after that removed the legacy files as in the article you suggested and now the administrator is showing  - "404 - Component not found" and the site is still showing the same thing. If this matters anyhow - when I started updtading it stopped right after I clicked the "Update" button. Stated downloading and after a few seconds it showed me these things -  as if it was interrupted somehow.
Thank you very much again for interest in my problem, but I already think to restore to backup.

Comment: @Ellie - did you read the following before trying to migrate? https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_2.5_to_3.x_Step_by_Step_Migration

Comment: Yes, I did. And did all the steps except "Set up a Development Location" from step 3 to step 9 :/ I assume they were the most important? :/ Now can I restore my site from the backup I have or I screwed up everything? :(